# How to handle java request in server side?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, javafx

I am student and I am actually new to Javafx or java world, but I like programming...

In my room I have an old computer, I made it as a Server for test. (Ubuntu Server Operating System).
In this Server, I installed Apache at port 80 and Tomcat at port 8080.

Now I have developed very simple Login GUI using Javafx. Now I want do "Login in" or "Sign up", I have 4 ideas(questions) and  1 Problems:

`Client-Side:1 Problem`

1. User click "Login in", what is the normal way to do such a request? I mean, I should firstly get the username and password; and then MD5(password); and then username.getbytes(), password.getbytes(); and then java Serialization; then transfer them to server side. Am i right? or should I need some cryptograph in the transfer process?

`Serve-Side: 4 ideas or questions`

1. The Server (my old Ubuntu server computer) get the request from Javafx GUI Application. Then how can I make such things, and response? 
   I mean:
2. If I want using Java Codes to handel the request under Http Apache Server (port 80),    what should I do? I mean, write a Java Programm, and then how run it in Http Server? If a use PHP, will it the same?
3. If I want using Java Codes to handel the request under Tomcat Apache Server (port 8080), what should I do?
4. If I self write a Java Programm at some any port (e.g. 9999), something like: while(true) serverSocket.acceppt();}(at port 9999 e.g.) , what should I do , I should run it under Tomcat or Apache? Or what should I do? I really do not know....
5. If I want using Apache to forward the request to tomcat, I should use somethink like mod_jk or mod_proxy, right?

I need some help about one Concept or direction.

Comment: Too many questions in single post.

Answer (score 0):

**Client-Side:1 Problem**

The normal process of using the authentication is to store the user passwords on the server and then every time the user wants to login, the server matches the password against the already stored password in the server. If it matches, then the user session starts.

You can have your password stored on the server as plain text (not at all recommended) or in encrypted form. If you decide to store it in the encrypted form then every time the user provides the password, you must encrypt it on the client side using java script encryption libraries and match it against the password saved on the server. For sending the encrypted password to the server you can use either ajax (e.g. JQuery) or just HTML submit method. 
Serve-Side: 4 ideas or questions

**The Server (my old Ubuntu server computer) get the request from Javafx GUI Application. Then how can I make such things, and response? I mean:**

**If I want using Java Codes to handel the request under Http Apache Server (port 80), what should I do? I mean, write a Java Programm, and then how run it in Http Server? If a use PHP, will it the same?**

If you decide to build your server with Java language, then you can only have tomcat server (which is actually a servlet container). Each request on the server (such as for user login) is handled by a backend servlet which receives the HTTP request from the client side and performs the required operation. You can also write [JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html).

If you decide to use PHP then you only need apache server and not tomcat server. For php, every request is handled by a PHP file on the server.

**If I want using Java Codes to handel the request under Tomcat Apache Server (port 8080), what should I do?
If I self write a Java Programm at some any port (e.g. 9999), something like: while(true) serverSocket.acceppt();}(at port 9999 e.g.) , what should I do , I should run it under Tomcat or Apache? Or what should I do? I really do not know....**

Writing a customer java program which listens to HTTP request on a specific port is called a server program and apache or apache tomcat are nothing but these program already written and provided for free. So, only in very specific situation you might decide to write your own but for sure having a login authorization doesn't require it.

**If I want using Apache to forward the request to tomcat, I should use somethink like mod_jk or mod_proxy, right?**

This is don't know.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wanna vore to you, but my level too low, can not, but thanks!@user3228556       What should I do for authentification system? I mean, for question 1, if the password matches the password, which is stored in database, then authentication should return true, right? Then what should I do about session or cookies? What is that normal way? I mean, I set UserId as Cookie in the client side, and some session in database or? How to implement automatically login in?